# How can I add a paragraph (as default) in the node form by using hook_form_alter in Drupal 8?

Tags: drupal, drupal-8, paragraph

I am trying to add a bunch of different empty paragraphs of different types, to a entity reference revisions field, everytime a node of a certain content type is created.
I DON'T want to use the contrib module "default paragraphs" for this, because I need to use a certain form widget here, and default paragraphs is also achieved by a widget.

What I tried so far:

```
function myModule_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id){

    $paragraph = \Drupal\paragraphs\Entity\Paragraph::create([
        'type' => 'tab_features'
      ]);
      $paragraph->save();

      $form['field_tabs']['widget'][0]['target_id']=$paragraph->id();
      $form['field_tabs']['widget'][0]['target_revision_id']=$paragraph->getRevisionId();

      return $form;
    }
```

$field_tabs is my entity reference revisions field.
'tab_features' is the paragraphs type I want to add.

I guess there should be a method that can be used in the form or form widget to add a paragraph to the form, like someone already clicked the button to add it. I want to avoid to actually trigger this via Javascript if possible. Anybody knows how to do this in form_alter?

Answer (score 0):

In a project I'm working on, we have done something like this:

```
    //get the body field
    $field = $entity->get('field_em_p_body');
    $paragraph = Paragraph::create([
        'type' => 'em_section', // Paragraph type.
      ]);
      $paragraph->isNew();
      $paragraph->set('YOUR_FIELD', 'SOMETHING');
      $field->appendItem($paragraph);
```